# How to change IPython QTConsole font on Linux

Tags: ubuntu, ipython, rhel, qtconsole, anaconda

I have been using ipython qtconsole on Win7 and recently I started using RHEL 6.x desktop. When I launch qtconsole ($ ipython qtconsole on bash prompt), the qt window I get has weird font, feel pointy, uneven, sort of like very old raster blocky font. I would like to use system fonts (like Monospace, DejaVu Sans Mono etc.) instead.

I tried to change some settings, as advised in another thread (like IPythonWidget.font_family in ipython_config.py and ipython_qtconsole_config.py), but the font family does not change. However, when I change the font size, I can make it smaller or larger.

I have tried to do this on RHEL and Ubuntu desktops without luck. I am using Anaconda's IPython distribution.

Comment: Can you try with a 'native' installation (e.g. `apt-get install ipython-qtconsole` on Ubuntu)? I wonder if it's related to Anaconda somehow.

Comment: It installs a terminal version of ipython-qtconsole. I don't see any QT interface here.

Comment: ? qtconsole is the Qt interface. Run `ipython qtconsole` at a terminal to start it, or find 'IPython Qt console' in the launcher.

Comment: This is an issue with Anaconda. The Anaconda QT is not building with font support correctly.

Comment: Tried that. It may be a QT Console or it may not be. I can only check if I can use some inline plots. This brings me to my second point, how can I get a distribution that bundles scipy, numpy, pandas and bunch of other scientific packages without having to install them manually (reason for choosing Anaconda distribution to begin with)

Thanks!

Comment: I downloaded Enthought's distribution and it seems to provide a good editor that would suffice for me use on Linux. I guess ipython qt on  Anaconda distribution is unusable for my needs.

Comment: Enthought Canopy Express also has the IPython qtconsole and Notebook installed.